# How do I use the Pumping Lemma with length to prove that the a language is nonregular?

Tags: formal-languages

Which one of the choices is the correct one and how do I get to the answer:

> The following question is given: Use the Pumping Lemma with length to prove that the following language is nonregular: $$L=\{bab^{n-2}a^n,\text{ with }n\in\{3,4,5,\ldots\},n\in\Bbb Z\}\;.$$ The solution to this question is partly given as follows:
>
> Assume $L=\{bab^{n-2}a^n,\text{ where }n\in\{3,4,5,\ldots\},n\in\Bbb Z\}$ is regular. Then there exists an FA with, say $k$ states that accepts $L$.
>
> Let $w=bab^{k-2}a^k$ be a word in $L$.
>
> According to the pumping lemma, $w$ may be written as $w=xyz$ such that $\operatorname{length}(x)+\operatorname{length}(y)\le k$ AND $\operatorname{length}(y)>0$.
>
> Which one of the following is **not** one of the possible correct choices for $y$?
>
> 1. $y$ comprises the $a$ in between $b$ and $b^{k-2}$.
> 2. $y$ comprises the first $ba$-substring.
> 3. $y$ comprises $ba$ followed by possible $b$’s.
> 4. $y$ comprises $ba$ followed by a possible second $ba$ substring.

I would like to know the answer and how to get to the answer. How do I know what can be $x$, $y$ and $z$. That's the part I don't understand.
Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  Please type your questions instead of posting images.  Images can't be browsed and are not accessible to those using screen readers.  If you need help formatting math on this site, here's a [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: You know that $xy$ is an initial segment of $w$, and you know that its length is at most $k$. The first $k$ characters of $w$ are $bab^{k-2}$, so $xy$ is an initial segment of $bab^{k-2}$. You know that $y$ has to be a non-empty string, because its length is greater than $0$, but $x$ can be empty or non-empty. That is all the information that you need in order to eliminate one of the four choices as a possible value of $y$.

Comment: Is the answer option 4?

Comment: @ Brian M. Scott, thank you. You make cs easier.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is choice 4 and here is why that is so:

We know that xy is an initial segment of w, and we know that its length is at most k. The first k characters of w are $bab^{k−2}$, so xy is an initial segment of $bab^{k−2}$. We know that y has to be a non-empty string, because its length is greater than 0, but x can be empty or non-empty. And by this information we can eliminate one of the four choices as a possible value of y.